# Can not interact with the deployed contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethers.js, hardhat, mainnet

getting this error

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data
at Proxy.getDecimals (contracts/proxy.sol:100)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

when using hardhat (forked mainnet/testnet). I am trying to read from a basic function decimals() of WETH.

My implementation is like this

```
interface ERC20 {
      function decimals() external returns (uint8); 
}

contract Proxy {
      function getDecimals(address _addr) external returns (uint8){
              return ERC20(_addr).decimals();
      }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you're calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `decimals()` being a **non-view** function, it should be marked as **view** function.
Try updating your ERC20 interface like this:

```
interface ERC20 {
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}
```

Same for `getDecimals` function.

Also, ensure that the contract you call implements `decimals()` function, if not you may encounter this error as well.